# yogurt on a pid controller: where to ask

Tags: discussion, scope

I have built a pid controller that I am using to make yogurt, but I am having trouble tuning it because of the change of thermal conductivity during the culture. Where is the best place to ask about it EE.SE, Chemistry.SE, ENG.SE or Cooking.SE? I am afraid that pid questions would thoroughly confuse the folks over at cooking. Although Chemistry.SE does have a cooking tag, they have no pid tag or open pid questions, Eng.SE does have a pid tag, but my question is about the interaction of the software and the food. Where Should I ask?

Comment: Wow, and I always just set the pan over a pilot-light :-)

Comment: What can I say, I like yogurt and I like pid controllers. Cooking with a pid controller is lots of fun, but making an improvised crockpot with a hotplate, cast iron pan, and a pid controller is real tricky.

Comment: I have a book around here titled "Stable Adaptive Systems" that may be relevant to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either here on EE.SE (we had controller questions in the past), or on Engineering.SE (versed in heat transfer).

You could post it here first. If it doesn't pick up, then post a flag to the moderators with custom text along the lines of "*Please migrate this question of mine to Engineering.SE.*"  We'll migrate it.

*p.s.* Do not cross-post the same question to multiple stacks, though.  StackExchange policy is against cross-posting.

Comment: Thankyou. Asked at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229765/yogurt-on-a-pid-controller